# php drop down retain selection

Tags: php

Retain selection for drop down after user hits the submit button
im just working with days 1-4 any help would be greatly appreciatted
go easy im a noob

```
<?PHP
    $day = array( );
    $day[0] = "1";
    $day[1] = "2";
    $day[2] = "3";
    $day[3] = "4";
    $days=$day;   
?>

<select name="day"> 
     <option value="day">Day</option>
     <?PHP
        for ($days = 0; $days < 4; $days++) {           
            print"<option value='$day[$days]'>$day[$days]</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: PHP doesn't have dropdowns. :)

Comment: You need to check the selection value conditionally in PHP.

Comment: I do not understood what your question is about. Please be more specific.

Comment: Try to use foreach instead of for.. 
    foreach ( $days as $d )
    {
        print "<option value='$d'>$d</option>";
    }

Comment: What is the "action" page in your form tag?  Usually you don't want to re-display the form once it is submitted by PHP.  There is something called javascript form validation that you should do instead, so that the form isn't submitted prematurely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pull the value passed in out of the `$_REQUEST` superglobal and check for it on each iteration. The `<option>` tag that you want preselected should include the `selected` attribute. Also, there is no need to create an array of consecutive integers when you can simply increment a counter in a loop. Something like this should work for you:

```
<select name="day"> 
<option value="day">Day</option>
<?php
    $day = null;
    if (array_key_exists('day', $_REQUEST) {
        $day = $_REQUEST['day'];
    }
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
       echo '<option value="' . $i . '"';
       if ($i == $day) {
           echo ' selected="selected"';
       }
       echo '>' . $i . "</option>\n";
    }
?>
</select>
```

Comment: hmm nothing works :{ perhaps i did not explain well but how would you guys go on to do a drop down for date of birth (user registration) i dont want to do this                             <select name="year"> 
 <option value="year">Year</option>
 <option value="1950">1950</option>                     <optionvalue="1951">1951</option>                                                      <option value="1952">1952</option>             </select> etc

Comment: yours works but on a different drop down i want it on the same drop down

Comment: @bob12345 This technique should work the same on all dropdowns. You may have the `name` attributes on your `select` elements reversed.

Comment: sorry it was my fault your code works perfectly just what i was looking for thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

For starters, that code needs some serious rethinking.

You are first creating an array then adding it to a different variable for no reason.

Secondly, your values are only one number away from the index, you can easily compute this on the fly.

And finally, you are looping inside that same array to make use of just the index (there is no need for the array).

So, to put some code where my mouth lies, it would look like:

```
<select name="day"> 
    <option value="day">Day</option>
    <?php
        for ($day = 1; $day <= 4; $day++) {
            print"<option value='$day'>$day</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

---

That said, you never mentioned which item needs to be selected. Assuming it is a variable called `$the_day`, here's yet some more code:

```
<?php

$the_day = 4;

?><select name="day"> 
    <option value="day">Day</option>
    <?php
        for ($day = 1; $day <= 4; $day++) {
            $it_is = $day == $the_day ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
            print"<option value='$day' $it_is>$day</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use selected keyword in your statement

```
print"<option value='$day[$days]' selected='selected'>$day[$days]</option>";
```