# preserve user choices in a HTML select element using PHP

Tags: php, select, input

I been struggling with PHP using the **select element** to preserve user input when not all of the fields are not filled properly and the form is submitted.

```
<form action="" method="post">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
    <select name="cars">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

with the input element, I can get away with a simple function like this:

```
function input_value($x){
    if(isset($_POST[$x])) {
    echo $_POST[$x];
    }else{
    echo '';
    }
}
```

and caling it like so:

```
<input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php input_value('fname');?>">
```

and the values are being preserved. but with the select element, its not.

so any help on how i can simply preserve the user input using a custom function if possible is greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11865345/php-drop-down-retain-selection

Comment: Added how you need to write the code for the `<select>` tag post form submit! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The select element does not have a `value` attribute to set the default selected option. Instead, the option element has a `selected` attribute. If you include it in the option element, it says "hey I'm selected". ;)

I would suggest you to replace the `echo` statement from the `input_value()` function with `return`:

```
function input_value($x){
    if (isset($_POST[$x])) {
        return $_POST[$x];
    }
    else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

Which enables you to do something like this:

```
<select name="cars">
    <option value="volvo" <?php echo (input_value('cars') == 'volvo') ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab" <?php echo (input_value('cars') == 'saab') ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes" <?php echo (input_value('cars') == 'mercedes') ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi" <?php echo (input_value('cars') == 'audi') ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Audi</option>
</select>
```

Don't forget to `echo` the result of the function in your 'normal' text fields:

```
<input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo input_value('fname');?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't working because you can't just set a value to your select input. You need to add the `"selected"` attribute to the `<option>` which was previously selected.

Answer (score 1):

Try this inside your select box

```
<option value="volvo" <?php echo (input_value('cars') == 'volvo') ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?> >Volvo</option>
```

EDIT:

Modify your `input_value($x)` function as

```
function input_value($x){
    if (isset($_POST[$x])) {
        return $_POST[$x];
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [`jquery-cookie`](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) for reading, writing and deleting cookies.

You can do this way:

1. Create session cookie:

   ```
    $.cookie('userInput', 'selectValue');
   ```
2. Read cookie:

   ```
    $.cookie('userInput'); // => "selectValue"
   ```
3. Using that, set the `selected` attribute for the `option`.

#### Or for the `$_POST` function:

You need to use the code this way:

```
<select name="cars">
  <option value="volvo"<?php echo (input_value('cars') == 'volvo') ? ' selected="selected"' : ""; ?>>Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab"<?php echo (input_value('cars') == 'saab') ? ' selected="selected"' : ""; ?>>Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes"<?php echo (input_value('cars') == 'mercedes') ? ' selected="selected"' : ""; ?>>Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi"<?php echo (input_value('cars') == 'audi') ? ' selected="selected"' : ""; ?>>Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
function input_value($x){
        if(isset($_POST[$x])) {
        return $_POST[$x];
        }else{
        return null;
        }
    }
```

and you can call like this

`<input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo input_value('fname');?>">`